# javaScript upload multiple files - when it has finished

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have this javascript function to upload files and I want to know when all files are uploaded, so when upload of multiple files has finished. 
Is there a possibility to do this?

```
function uploadFiles(files, userId, projectId, successCallback, progressCallback) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              if (!file.$error) {
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'api/fileuploads/fileupload/' + userId + '/' + projectId,
                    data: {
                      file: file  
                    }
                }).then(function (resp) {
                    if (successCallback) {
                        successCallback(resp);
                    }
                }, null, function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    var log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name + '\n';
                    if (progressCallback) {
                        progressCallback(log);
                    }
                });
              }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Is there any framework you are using? In most framework there's a way to wait for multiple promises to resolve. Google this: javascript wait for multiple promises

Comment: What is `file.$error`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from()` or `.slice()` to convert `files` object to array, `.map()` `Promise.all()`

```
function uploadFiles(files, userId, projectId, successCallback, progressCallback) {
  if (files && files.length) {    
    return Promise.all(Array.from(files)).map(function(file) {
        return Upload.upload({
          url: 'api/fileuploads/fileupload/' 
               + userId + '/' + projectId,
          data: {
            file: file
          }
        }).then(function(resp) {
          if (successCallback) {
            successCallback(resp);
          }
        }
        // what is second parameter to `.then()`?
        // why is `null` passed here?
        , null, function(evt) {
          var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
          var log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' 
                    + evt.config.data.file.name + '\n';
          if (progressCallback) {
            progressCallback(log);
          }
        });
    })
  }
};
```

Usage

```
uploadFiles(/* parameters */)
.then(function() {
  console.log("all uploads complete")
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a counter that will count how many times Upload promise have resolved:

```
function uploadFiles(files, userId, projectId, successCallback, progressCallback) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            var count = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              if (!file.$error) {
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'api/fileuploads/fileupload/' + userId + '/' + projectId,
                    data: {
                      file: file  
                    }
                }).then(function (resp) {
                    if (++count == files.length) {
                        if (successCallback) {
                            successCallback(resp);
                        }
                    }
                }, null, function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    var log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name + '\n';
                    if (progressCallback) {
                        progressCallback(log);
                    }
                });
              }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all or jQuery.when

```js
function uploadFiles(files, userId, projectId, successCallback, progressCallback) {
    
        if (files && files.length) {
            var uploads = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              if (!file.$error) {
                var upload = Upload.upload({
                    url: 'api/fileuploads/fileupload/' + userId + '/' + projectId,
                    data: {
                      file: file  
                    }
                }).then(function (resp) {
                    if (successCallback) {
                        successCallback(resp);
                    }
                }, null, function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    var log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name + '\n';
                    if (progressCallback) {
                        progressCallback(log);
                    }
                });
                uploads.push(upload);
              }
              
            }
            Promise.all(uploads).then(function(values){});
        }
     
    };
```